# "During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed." error on gdb run

Tags: c, macos, gdb

I'm a very novice C programmer and have some problem using gdb tool.
When I compile a source file and try to run on gdb, I get this following error.

```
[New Thread 0x200b of process 22844]
[New Thread 0x2303 of process 22844]
During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

I've looked at other threads mentioning this problem, but I could not really figure out any "actionable" solution. They are mostly for C++ and I didn't understand. I really appreciate your help!

Edit: Some clarifications..

This happens for me for any optimization (-Og, -O1, -O2) I use.

For example for the following C programming

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Hello World!");
}
```

when I compile by using the following command

```
gcc -Og test.c
gcc -O1 test.c
gcc -O2 test.c
```

(either one of those)
I get

```
./a.out.
```

Then when I put

```
gdb ./a.out
```

on the command line, and insert

```
run
```

I get the error.

```
[New Thread 0x200b of process 22844]
[New Thread 0x2303 of process 22844]
During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
```

This is really not specific to what kind of programming I use. Also,

```
./a.out
```

runs perfectly without gdb.

Comment: Does this also happen with a "Hello World" program? How do you compile? What compiler flags do you use?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, it happens no matter what program I wrote. I tried -Og, -O1, -O2, or no flag at all. I did not have any success and got the same message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What happens if you run the same program without `gdb`?

Comment: @MinSeokSong please [edit] and tell us: - your platform, - your compiler, - the exact verbatim command line you use when you compile, -etc.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. It runs perfectly when i just execute the binary code.

Comment: Then it is not impossible that you have some bad `gdb` version/installation. But you should still show us exactly what you are doing, as it is not the only possibility.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would cause segfault. Which version of `gdb` do you have?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I am using GNU gdb (GDB) 13.2. I'm struggling with this for the past few weeks without any success.

Comment: Well, it's recent. I can only suggest trying to downgrade it a bit and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Thanks for your suggestion. That's weird tbh..

Comment: What is your OS? Looks like it is macOS.

Comment: If you give GDB the command `set startup-with-shell off` followed by `run`, does that make any difference?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick
Yes, it does. I get this.

Comment: Starting program: /Users/minseoksong/Desktop/c practice/a.out 
[New Thread 0x2003 of process 27716]
[New Thread 0x2903 of process 27716]
warning: unhandled dyld version (17)
Hello World![Inferior 1 (process 27716) exited normally]

Comment: @ks1322 Yes, I use mac

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why this kind of behavior happened in my gdb. I used my computer fairly normally.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks! I just started using gdb and ran into this problem, and `set startup-with-shell-off` seems to have fixed it for now. I guess there's likely some env variable that's set somewhere which disappears when gdb creates a new shell?